# .NET importing, remove ending columns that have empty header column

Tags: c#, .net, linq, csv, textfieldparser

I have a CSV file that has over 16,000 columns to import.  However, the file really only has up to 12 columns, with two empty headers in between.  In the screenshot what is the best way to remove the 12 index and up to the 16,000 from the header array quickly in .NET? 8,9 should stay since 10,11 have header values.  Right now I am going through every column on each row, meaning 16,000 checks per row when it should be 12 (0-11 index).

```
 protected Dictionary<int, string> Headers = new Dictionary<int, string>();
```

[image]

Comment: Are the columns always the same? If not, you could loop backwards to figure out the max index to loop to before doing your actual work

Comment: I mean we could have a file that has 15,000 columns and 14,990 of those are empty columns.

Comment: So looping backwards through the headers first, figuring out the last column index where there's something, and then using that for looping. I'd include a few more lines If I were you, I could help you more

Comment: Yea, how would I go about doing that, linq?

Comment: Add a little bit more code, like variable declarations, and perhaps as code, not a screenshot.

Comment: I added my dictionary array, that is all that is really needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would loop backwards to figure out the last index in the header array where there's something.

```
int lastColumn = 0;

for (lastColumn = columns.Length - 1; lastColumn >= 0 ; lastColumn--)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(columns[i]))
    {
        break;
    }
}

// stop at lastColumn, skipping all the empty columns at the end
for (int i = 0; i <= lastColumn; i++)
{
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: 11 is the index, 12th in the array

Comment: @MikeFlynn if this solves your problem, please mark my answer as the correct one. Thanks!